# How can I insert text in the clipboard from an assembly program running in DOSBox?

Tags: assembly, x86, clipboard, dos, dosbox

I have a db variable in assembly containing a string, like so:

```
STR_VAR db 'test$'
```

Is it possible to copy this variable to the clipboard, so that when a user presses Ctrl+V in another program (such as word) it will paste the text in the variable.

EDIT:
Important info:
I am using DOSBox to run the code

Comment: OS as in operating system? I am using windows but I run my code in DOSBox

Comment: And does DOS have a clipboard? It doesn't seem so but I don't remember.

Comment: I believe [INT 2F/AX=1703h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-4639.htm) might be usable.  It might be required to load the (WinOldAp) appropriate driver before though.

Comment: Ah yes, that would work with a DOS application running in NTVDM, but I doubt it'll work in dosbox.  Maybe there is a DOSBOX API?

Comment: It looks like this feature was very recently added to dosbox, see https://github.com/joncampbell123/dosbox-x/wiki/Guide:Clipboard-support-in-DOSBox%E2%80%90X#copy-and-paste-text-using-a-dos-program.  There is a `CLIP$` device, and apparently the old Windows 3.1 API is supported too.

Comment: @ItaiElidan: Please edit your question to include the important information that you are talking about dosbox (and add the [tag:dosbox] tag).  Otherwise people are likely to think the question is unclear and downvote it.

Comment: @NateEldredge DOSBox-X ≠ DOSBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in TASM syntax there are a few additions and changes you need to make so it will work with the newest DOSBOX-X.
Here is the final working version

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

STR_VAR DB 'test',0
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

        mov     ax,  1700h   ; IdentifyWinOldApVersion
        int     2fh
        cmp     ax,  1700h
        jz      error_2

        mov     ax,  1701h   ; OpenClipboard
        int     2fh
        test    ax, ax
        jz      error_2

        mov     ax,  1709h   ; ClipboardCompact
        mov     cx, 5  ; STR_VAR.end - STR_VAR
        xor     si, si
        int     2fh
        ;cmp     dx, si
        ;jb      error_2
        ;ja      fits
        cmp dx, 0
        jne fits
        cmp ax, 0
        je error_2
        jmp fits
        cmp     cx, ax
        jb      error_2

fits:
        mov     ax,  1703h   ; SetClipboardData
        mov     dx, 7        ; CF_OEMTEXT
        mov     bx, offset STR_VAR
        ; ES and SI:CX already set up
        push ds
        pop es
        int     2fh
        test    ax, ax
        jz      error_2
        
        mov     ax,  1708h   ; CloseClipboard
        int     2fh


       mov     ax,  4c00h
        int      21

error_2:
        mov     ax,  4c01h
        int      21

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Answer (score 3):

There actually is an official API for DOS for accessing the host’s clipboard, supported in Windows 3.x and 9x. It is briefly described in article [Q67675](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/067/Q67675/), formerly in Microsoft’s Knowledge Base.

Here’s a code sample (NASM syntax):

```nasm
org 0x100

        mov     ax, 0x1700   ; IdentifyWinOldApVersion
        int     0x2f
        cmp     ax, 0x1700
        jz      error

        mov     ax, 0x1701   ; OpenClipboard
        int     0x2f
        test    ax, ax
        jz      error

        mov     ax, 0x1709   ; ClipboardCompact
        mov     cx, STR_VAR.end - STR_VAR
        xor     si, si
        int     0x2f
        cmp     dx, si
        jb      error
        ja      .fits
        cmp     cx, ax
        jb      error

.fits:
        mov     ax, 0x1703   ; SetClipboardData
        mov     dx, 7        ; CF_OEMTEXT
        mov     bx, STR_VAR
        ; ES and SI:CX already set up
        int     0x2f
        test    ax, ax
        jz      error
        
        mov     ax, 0x1708   ; CloseClipboard
        int     0x2f

        mov     ax, 0x4c00
        int     0x21

error:
        mov     ax, 0x4c01
        int     0x21

STR_VAR:
        db      'test'
.end:
```

I am very doubtful however that vanilla DOSBox actually supports this API (though it is apparently supported in DOSBox-X, a fork).

Comment: Hey, It would help me if you could answer it in TASM syntax. Thanks